# Eigen: matrix-matrix multiplication does not support multi-threading within an MPI process?

Tags: multithreading, openmp, eigen, openmpi, eigen3

I am trying to use Eigen with multi-threading within the head process of an MPI program. Without MPI the Eigen multi-threading works fine for matrix-matrix multiplications.

When using MPI initialized with MPI_Init_thread(...), although Eigen::nbThreads() returns the correct number of threads, Eigen actually only uses only one thread.

Sample code:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include "omp.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
using Eigen::VectorXd;
using namespace Eigen;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int numprocs, rank;
    int iam = 0, np = 1;
    int threading = -1;
    int nthreads = 8;

    MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED, &threading);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    omp_set_num_threads(nthreads);
#pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(iam, np)
    {
        np = omp_get_num_threads();
        iam = omp_get_thread_num();
        std::cout << "Hello from thread " << iam << " out of " << np << " from process " << rank << " out of " << numprocs << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Testing eigen multithreading ..." << std::endl;
    Eigen::setNbThreads(nthreads); 
    Eigen::initParallel();
    std::cout << "Eigen: number of threads: " << Eigen::nbThreads() << std::endl;
    int flag;
    MPI_Is_thread_main(& flag);
    std::cout << "MPI_Is_thread_main: " << flag << std::endl;
    if (rank==0)
    {
        int n = 5000;
        MatrixXd A = MatrixXd::Ones(n,n);
        MatrixXd B = MatrixXd::Ones(n,n);
        MatrixXd C = MatrixXd::Ones(n,n);
        C.noalias() += A*B;
        std::cout << C.sum() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Testing eigen multithreading finished ..." << std::endl;

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Compile: `mpicxx -fopenmp hello.cpp -o hello -I./include`

Run: `mpirun -np 1 ./hello`
or,
`mpirun -np 1 -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 ./hello`

Output:

```
Hello from thread 0 out of 8 from process 0 out of 1
Hello from thread 7 out of 8 from process 0 out of 1
Hello from thread 6 out of 8 from process 0 out of 1
Hello from thread 5 out of 8 from process 0 out of 1
Hello from thread 4 out of 8 from process 0 out of 1
Hello from thread 3 out of 8 from process 0 out of 1
Hello from thread 2 out of 8 from process 0 out of 1
Hello from thread 1 out of 8 from process 0 out of 1
Testing eigen multithreading ...
Eigen: number of threads: 8
MPI_Is_thread_main: 1
...
```

It seems the MPI-OpenMP hybrid mode runs correctly out of the Eigen region. I am using Eigen-3.3.7. I tried openmpi-1.8.6 (ompi_info returns MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE: yes) and openmpi-4.0.2. The actual number of threads can be checked from the workload of CPU.

I wonder if I need to do something else to make it work or, for some reason, Eigen does not support this hybrid mode? Thanks!

Comment: With 1 or 2 processes, Open MPI binds each of them to a single core, preventing use of multi-threading. Try adding the command line option `--bind-to none` to prevent the binding.

Comment: @jacob Thanks! It worked.From the openmpi mpirun man page: If your application uses threads, then you probably want to ensure that you are either not bound at all (by specifying --bind-to none), or bound to multiple cores using an appropriate binding level or specific number of processing elements per application process.